# Android studio Build error + Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, build-error, processexception

I'm getting this error continuously.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

I've tried upgrade/downgrade gradle files/ removed libraries and add those again/ changed build tool version/ add cruncherEnabled = false in dependency and deleting build folder/ clear and rebuild project but nothing helped.

Same git project can be run in my another laptop but its not working in this device. Can anyone put me out of this misery?

Comment: Try to clean your project in `build` `clean project`

Comment: already done couple of times

Comment: Oh... sorry. didn't read to the end of your question.